# Keep, but deactivate stylesheets & scripts

Tags: javascript, performance

I have 4 pages, I use ajax and historyPopState to change betweens them. But there is a problem since the pages are very different they use different stylesheets and scripts. I could just download them over and over again, but I wanted to ask if there is a way how to keep it onpage, but only disabling it for a moment and reenable them when needed.
PS.:Those 4 pages have one stylesheet & one script in common.
PPS.: And I can't set headers (not access to all things in server)

Comment: If you set your headers properly, the browser won't keep downloading them over and over again: it will load from the local cache. Either that, or I really didn't understand what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @BrunoReis well exactly what you said, but I don't have full access. None access to php.ini (or whatever it is named)

Comment: What web server are you using? If you are running for example Apache Httpd, you might be able to add a .htaccess file on your application's folder to configure the headers for your static files. Or you could move all your static content to a different place, where you can set the headers the way you want. For example, you could use Amazon S3: you have the ability to set the relevant headers, and it's free for 1 year up to 5GB of storage.

Comment: Well for this moment a school one... but soon I'll have to build my own so it might be nice if you could send me a link how to do this Thanks in advice

Comment: Can you put all the CSS in one file, set a class on the body and wrap the right CSS in `body.page1 { }`, `body.page2 { }` etc. selectors? If you use a preprocessor (Less, SASS) it would be pretty easy. For JS this would probably be a lot harder

Comment: @Phortuin - why don't you make your comment an answer?  That's what I was going to submit as an answer.

Comment: @Phortuin nice idea, but those files are large enough already and not all visitors look on all pages so they would download unnecessary parts too. Plus too much of nested selectors isn't good for loading speed.

Comment: can cache the content within your app once that page has been called...then won't need to request it each time

Comment: jfriend00, because I wasn't sure if this was a viable option (@Akxe suggests he has little control over assets). @Akxe I agree that it wouldn't be bandwidth-friendly, but what you are proposing in your question (disabling/reenabling parts) would mean that all CSS/JS is always available on every page. And that would have the same effect on page load as my idea

Comment: @Phortuin technically not everything have to be loaded. Pages that wasn't visited shouldn't have theirs parts downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript you can disable stylesheets by accessing the `styleSheets` object on the `document` and setting `disabled` to `true`:
(tested in Chrome and IE9. I couldn't find any useful statistics on compatibility for this)

```
document.styleSheets[0].disabled = true
```